# redirect all views in django if a condition is met

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a field on my user profile model to see if a user:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    ...
    password_change_required = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Is their a way I can redirect all views like this:

```
if request.user.profile.password_change_required:
     redirect(....)
```

Where can I put this logic so it hits all views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/):

> During the request phase, before calling the view, Django applies
>   middleware in the order it’s defined in MIDDLEWARE, top-down.
>
> You can think of it like an onion: each middleware class is a “layer”
>   that wraps the view, which is in the core of the onion. If the request
>   passes through all the layers of the onion (each one calls
>   get_response to pass the request in to the next layer), all the way to
>   the view at the core, the response will then pass through every layer
>   (in reverse order) on the way back out.
>
> **If one of the layers decides to short-circuit and return a response
>   without ever calling its get_response, none of the layers of the onion
>   inside that layer (including the view) will see the request or the
>   response**. The response will only return through the same layers that
>   the request passed in through.

Which should do what you want so long as your ordering is correct (e.g. after auth middleware so `request.user` is available).

Answer (score 1):

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.profile.password_change_required:
        return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return redirect('/accounts/change-password/?next=%s' % request.path)
```

make sure you also import redirect

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```

Comment: Won't this only affect the ProfileUpdateView?

Comment: yes. It will only affect the ProfileUpdateView. If you want to apply it all Generic View classes, you may have to use Mixins

Comment: As stated in the question, I want it to apply to ALL views.